# String comparision with equals and compareTo - which is faster?

Tags: java, string

I need to compare 2 `Strings`. I have following methods I could think of:

1. `equalsIgnoreCase` - Heard that this is the fastest, but i can't use it as my String is case sensitive
2. `matches` - Probably the slowest one
3. `equals`
4. `compareTo`

So in the above option, I am left with `equals` and `compareTo`. Which one is faster among these?

**Note:** Input number of Strings are huge in number [around 5000 per sec].

Comment: I very much doubt that `equalsIgnoreCase` is faster than others. Must be slower because it needs to do more.

Comment: Any specific reason why equals is faster?

Comment: equals is very fast for strings of different length.

Comment: Best way to find out is to measure it. Note that the situation may change with different platform versions.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing? What Strings are you comparing? I think it really depends on the situation (i.e. if you compare strings already in the string pool or if you compare new ones). compareTo will not be #1 because it has to check if the incoming object is a String first and will then (propabbly through the equals method) check if the Strings are equal.

Comment: Why just not to run test code and check what is better in your particular case?

Comment: @G.S It doesn't matter which is faster. What you're doing is micro-optimization, the actual slow parts in your program are elsewhere.

Comment: `String#equals` and `String#compareTo` are of the same complexity. You should use the one you deem more appropriate for the situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the quickest way to compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805601/whats-the-quickest-way-to-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339870/fastest-way-to-compare-strings-literal-and-numerical).

Comment: Just *use the "correct" comparison based on what is needed* (it sounds like `equals`). 5000/second is likely *nothing* for a modern CPU (although one come point to degenerate data cases). If there is a performance bounds issue it will be due to another algorithm selection or bottleneck (where are your profile numbers?!?). I honestly don't understand why such micro-optimization questions (*that can be tested*) get so much [positive] attention ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Strings: compareTo() vs. equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note a very important difference between [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) and [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
"myString".compareTo(null);  //Throws java.lang.NullPointerException
"myString".equals(null);     //Returns false
```

Now I advise you to review the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) of both methods to conclude that `equals` is preferable over `compareTo` that involves some [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) calculations.

Also note that `equals` makes a `==` first! This might be a big advantage when the objects are identical. Specially when you mentioned that you have a huge amount of Strings, because Java interns Strings, this might happen more than you thought.

---

Although you asked about Strings, but I want to add this note:
These methods can be very different when `BigDecimal` is involved. For example, see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> **equals** compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality.
>   **Unlike compareTo**, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
>   only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
>   2.00 when compared by this method).

Answer (score 6):

> I am left with equals and compareTo.

Both serves in different purposes.

```
CompareTo
```

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Where as

```
equals
```

> true if the given object represents a String equivalent to this string, false otherwise

Hence `compareTo()` need more calculations that `equals()`

You can see the proof of that in source code of both.

[compareTo()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

[equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)   ----- prefer to use this.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source code of both methods it appears that `String#compareTo` is of the same complexity as `String#equals`.

Comment: @BenBarkay It's not always about complexity. For example, `equals` first uses `==`, which is much faster when the Strings are identical.

Comment: @MarounMaroun it's true, but if you ever get to the point where you repeatedly compare a string with itself to make this a significant performance gain, the real problem is likely to be something other than your choice of comparison method.

Comment: @BenBarkay Indeed. But since Java `intern` Strings, the `==` comparison might be happening more than we thought :)

Answer (score 2):

> equalsIgnoreCase

You generally use this one for string comparison.

> matches

Slow because it is RegEx-based.

> equals

I don't think this is slower than `equalsIgnoreCase`

> compareTo

This returns an integer, or 0. This is used in sorting, for example. Don't use it for equality.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 main differences are that:

```
equals will take any Object as a parameter, but compareTo will only take Strings.
equals only tells you whether they're equal or not, but compareTo gives information on how the Strings compare lexicographically.
```

ANd this is the class code url http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html.
U can also look at this post if u want
[Java Strings: compareTo() vs. equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals)

Answer (score 1):

***Equals -***

1- Override the GetHashCode method to allow a type to work correctly in a hash table.

2- Do not throw an exception in the implementation of an Equals method. Instead, return false for a null argument.

3-

```
 x.Equals(x) returns true.

 x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).

 (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true if and only if x.Equals(z) returns true.
```

Successive invocations of x.Equals(y) return the same value as long as the object referenced by x and y are not modified.

```
 x.Equals(null) returns false.
```

4- For some kinds of objects, it is desirable to have Equals test for value equality     instead of referential equality. Such implementations of Equals return true if the two    objects have the same value, even if they are not the same instance.

For Example -

```
  Object obj1 = new Object();
  Object obj2 = new Object();
  Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));
  obj1 = obj2; 
  Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));
```

Output :-

```
  False
  True
```

while ***compareTo*** -

Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance precedes, follows, or occurs in the same position in the sort order as the other object.

It returns -

Less than zero    - This instance precedes obj in the sort order.
Zero              - This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as obj.
Greater than zero - This instance follows obj in the sort order.

It can throw ArgumentException if object is not the same type as instance.

For example you can visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx).

So I suggest better to use Equals in place of compareTo.

Answer (score 0):

You can time the code yourself and see which is faster:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  // Do comparison here
}
final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time to execute: " + (end - start));
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
s1.CompareTo(s2)
```

> 0 - both equal
>
> +ve - than s2 is lexicographically lower than the s1
>
> -ve - than s2 is lexicographically higher than the s1

```
s1.equals(Object o1)
```

> true- if s1 and o1 equals
>
> false- if s1 and o1 not equal

`compareTo` can throw `ClassCastException` but `equals` if s1 and o1 are different class than should return false.

---

`TreeMap` depends on  `compareTo()` while `HashMap` depends on  `equals()`. So if you equals and compareTo are not consistent than `TreeMap` and `HashMap` can behave differently.  Hence it is good to have equals() and compareTo() consistent to each other but it's not mandatory.

---

I think the best or efficient way to compare string is to reference compare (but you should have used `literals` in your whole code). Because string inherently **immutable** and String class implements **FlyWeight** pattern inside by `intern()` method or by compiler. So it is good to compare reference.

if you are not confident about literals in code than you can do an optimization:

```
s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode() && s1.equals(s2)
```

This is because String in immutable.

Answer (score 0):

> equalsIgnoreCase - Heard that this is the fastest

Definitely not. It has to do things to promote lowercase to uppercase or *vice versa.* You can't have 'heard' that anywhere reputable.

> matches - Probably the slowest one

Agreed.

> equals
>   compareTo

There is no reason to expect a difference between these.